# How do you always refresh html Audio

Tags: javascript, html, caching, audio, html5-audio

My web application is based on generating and playing an audio file. Unfortunately, despite the audio file itself being updated (I know this because when I download it it's correct), the audio that is played on the website is a cached, old version. Even hard refreshing multiple times doesn't get past the cache. How can I reload the audio source.

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="/static/output.wav">
</audio>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "generating" audio? Sounds like you actually want to stream your media no? In that case you should probably try some streaming strategies, e.g an IceCast server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even hard refreshing multiple times doesn't get past the cache.

...

> Unfortunately, despite the audio file itself being updated (I know this because when I download it it's correct)

Those aren't the same HTTP request.  When you use the `<audio>` element, it will make ranged requests.  Something, somewhere along the way, is caching it.

In any case, all you need to do is set the appropriate `Cache-Control` header on the HTTP response.  Something like this will do:

```
Cache-Control: no-store
```

(Of course, you will actually need to flush your browser's cache, and any server-side caches before you'll see this take effect.)

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: Though I wonder what will happen when they'll request range 1-100 from file1 and then range 101-200 from file2... Ever experienced such a scenario?

Comment: @Kaiido Good question.  I think in this case, the client wouldn't know whether or not the backend actually swapped out the resource.  Maybe `ETag` helps, but I haven't tried.  In my own usage, I use unique IDs and don't reuse them, to get as much value out of caching and CDNs as possible.  Reading the question again, I think you might be right that this person wants to actually generate fresh audio in production, which presents other issues.